# UITableView and UILabel performance while displaying strange characters

Tags: ios, performance, uitableview, uilabel

I'm creating a small messaging application using a UITableView. Inside each cell there are a few UILabels. When the message label displays "strange" characters the performance takes a severe hit and I can't seem to find a way around this.

Example of the problematic cell:

[image]

```
 func getProfessionalChatCell(message: Message) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChatMessageCellLeft") as! ChatMessageCell
cell.messageContentText.text = message.content
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
return cell
```

}

Comment: you should consider uploading a code snippet which you used in your tableView methods

Comment: It may be Data which is causing problem not `UILabel` or `UITableView` can you put some light what kind of data are you trying to display? it looks like you have very big data in size plus decoding is also in process.

Comment: It's just text. In this case it's an ASCII drawing using special characters. There doesn't seem to be any other problem in cells without ASCII drawings, so it guess it must be the special characters. I'm uploading a code snippet.

Comment: You may need to decode message.content to get the correct text format.

Comment: Remove `cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true` because its not a good idea to use it in tableview cell as the cells are recreated and will create problems in scrolling..

Comment: I will remove shouldRasterize, I had it cause it improves performance on tablets where a lot of cells are drawn at the same time.

Comment: @KrishnaDattShukla how would I go about decoding the message?

Comment: Firstly You will need to know what exactly message.content is ? is it in ASCII or in some other format ?

Comment: Its text in UTF-8.